# Specify JDBI default plugin (SqlObjectPlugin)

Tags: java, jdbi, jdbi3

Is there a way to tell JDBI I want to use a specific plugin (SqlObjectPlugin in my case) throughout my entire application, without having to re-specify upon each use? Throughout my application code I have the following:

```
var jdbi = Jdbi.create(dataSource);
jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());  // <== I want to make this part DRY
```

I'm tired of having that second boilerplate line repeated all over my code.

To the JDBI devs: I totally love the product! thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, which of the is best depends on the code of your application:

1. Instantiate `Jdbi` once and reuse it everywhere (using DI, static singleton, etc)
2. Use `org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi#installPlugins`, which, according to documentation, `uses the ServiceLoader API to detect and install plugins automagically. Some people consider this feature dangerous; some consider it essential -- use at your own risk`. But you still would need to call this method every time.